# Проблема с post запросом на WorldPress

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь сделать запрос, чтобы добавить новый пост на WP сайт.
Однако все мои попытки заканчиваются `<Response [405]>`
Не смог ничего дельного найти в интернете.
Код:

```
import requests
import json
import base64
import cfg

url = cfg.site

user = cfg.user

password = cfg.pass

creds = user + ':' + password

token = base64.b64encode(creds.encode())

header = {'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + token.decode('utf-8')}

post = {
    'date' : '2020-08-30T10:00:00',
    'title' : 'TestPost',
    'content' : 'This is our first post',
    'status' : 'publish'
}

r = requests.post(url + '/posts', headers=header, json=post)
print(r)
```

Что нужно сделать, чтобы WP стал принимать такие запросы?

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, тело и заголовки ответа от wordpress

Comment: @Inventor Я запускаю скрипт и в конце вывожу r (response) и никак не могу понять почему он выдает ошибку error 405.

Какое тело и заголовки ответа от wordpress вам нужно?

Answer (score 0):

Если сервер возвращает код ответа `405 Method Not Allowed`, то это означает, что метод запроса (post в вашем случае) не разрешён. В заголовке ответа `ALLOW` сервер должен вернуть методы запроса, которые разрешены

Comment: Я не очень хорошо знаком с WorldPress'ом.  
Можете, пожалуйста, подробнее объяснить про ответ ```ALLOW```?

Comment: @AlexandrKiselev это никак не связано с WordPress. Это стандарт http, по которому общаются все серверы мира на чём бы и на каком языке они бы не были написаны. Изучите более подробно протокол http

Comment: я имел ввиду, что можно ли разрешить или как-то заставить сервер принимать post запросы?  
Во всех статьях и блогах, объясняющих как загрузить пост на WP через Python не было никаких танцев с бубнами)  
Поэтому очень интересно как это все работает)

Comment: @AlexandrKiselev а почему вы думаете, что все сайты на wp одинаковые? Всё зависит от кода, который написан для этого сайта. Можно заставить его принимать запросы, если у вас есть возможность редактировать код сайта

Comment: Да, я имею полный доступ к сайту. Я думал, что данные запросы обрабатывает Rest API. Разве нет?

Comment: Просто когда я передаю запрос ```http://сайт/wp-json/wp/v2/posts``` через браузер, то никакой ошибки не возникает. Поэтому я думаю, что именно в python что-то делаю не так

Comment: @AlexandrKiselev откуда я знаю, что обрабатывает эти запросы в ВАШЕМ коде?)) В Python коде никакой ошибки нет